# Cannot implicity convert type ApplicationUser to User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type
 'System.Collections.Generic.List<xxxx.Models.ApplicationUser>' to
 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<xxxx.User>'. An explicit
 conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I can't find anything related to this issue. I created an API-folder inside Controllers folder, added UserController in API folder and then wrote the following:

*(get the error at*  `return _context.Users.ToList();`*)*

```
namespace xxxx.Controllers.API {
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {

        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public UserController() {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        //GET /api/users
        public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
        {

            return _context.Users.ToList(); //<-- where I get the error message
        }
```

This is my model for user:

```
public partial class User
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public User()
    {            
        this.Reviews = new HashSet<Review>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The value returned from `_context.Users.ToList()` returns type `ApplicationUser` and not `User`.  `ApplicationUser` would need to derive from `User` for this to work, or return a list of `User`s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method returns `IEnumerable<User>`, but `_context.Users` must get you type `ApplicationUser`. You will have to convert these to type `User`, or have your method return `IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>`.

To do the conversion, I like to use `Transformers`. I usually implement an interface

```
public interface ITransformer<in TSource, out TOutput>
{
    TOutput Transform(TSource source);
}
```

An example transformer would be

```
public class AppUserToUserTransformer : ITransformer<ApplicationUser, User>
{
    public User Transform(ApplicationUser source)
    {
        return new User
        {
            Username = source.Username;
            Email = source.Email;
            //continue with the rest of the available properties
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I convert to type user? Also if I return `IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>`, I get error: `'IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`

Comment: I like to use `Transformers`. Basically, you make a method specific to converting `ApplicationUser` to `User`. It will only accept type `ApplicationUser` and will always return type `User`. Inside, you will just have to pick the properties off the `ApplicationUser` variable passed in and set them to your `new User`.

Comment: The question is not how you convert it to another type, the question is _why_ is it another type? Which type are you wanting to use?  Why have you got two types, `User` and `ApplicationUser`?

Comment: @Gavin Would you mind demonstrate how to do that? I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @Luke I don't know where `ApplicationUser` came from. I just followed a guide how to use API in mvc. I assume I got it from `ApplicationDbContext`.

Comment: We would need to see the definition of `ApplicationUser` to do that.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't return `IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>` from your method instead of `IEnumerable<User>`?

Comment: @Luke I haven't made `ApplicationUser` from own will, I guess I got it from `_context = new ApplicationDbContext();`

Comment: @Luke I get error from both - "`IEnumerable<X>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`". X= `User` or `ApplicationUser`

Comment: I guess it depends I used `ApplicationDbContext` this time(followed a guide)? I normally use `xxxxEntities db = new xxxxEntities()` for the rest in my project.

Comment: @skylake: That is normally what I do as well. `ApplicationUser` is made with a new MVC project. You can find it in `IndentityModel.cs`.

Comment: @Gavin I see, can I stick with xxxxEntities for API? Or is ApplicationDbContext required to use?

Comment: If `xxxxEntities` gives you access to the information you need then go ahead and use it.